# Asp.net web application crashes when retrieve data from an oracle DB

Tags: asp.net, oracle, subsonic, oracleclient

I have an asp.net website on a windows server 2003. The application connects to an oracle 10g R2 Database and the data layer is generated by subsonic.
The database and the application are on separate servers each.

On development machine the application runs normally. But On production server, there is a server error that occurs in pages that communicates with the database

The problem is that the error does not happen all the time, it is on and off and i can not debug it since it does not happen locally. if i refresh the page. everything works fine. but with another refresh the error might show again. 
And we started getting oracle client errors such as:

```
 - Transaction has completed; it is no longer usable
 - Invalid operation. The connection is closed
 - Unable to load DLL 'oramts.dll'
 - Attempted to read or write protected memory at   
   System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.OraMTSJoinTxn
```

I think the error is due to overload or performance.

Does anyone have an idea about the above problem?

Comment: Please post the actual exception details (Exception.ToString()).

Comment: @ShellShock below is the exception detail

Answer (score 0):

We managed to solve this problem, by moving the application and the database, each to another machine.
I most probably think, it was a server performance issue, or network disrupt between the application and the database (each was on a separate server machine).
We eliminated the code error case, since if it was so, the application wouldn't run at anytime but the pages were loading every now and then, or if you keep hitting f5.
And we kept getting oracle client errors.